# Symfony Doctrine OneToOne embedded form error_bubbling

Tags: php, forms, symfony, error-handling, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get the error message for an embedded form to display next to the form field that has the error.

I have 2 Doctrine entities connected with a OneToOne relationship as follows:

```
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Name", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $name;

}

class Name
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id

    /**
     * @var string $givenName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="given_name", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="Given name must not be blank."
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min="2",
     *     max="255",
     *     minMessage="Given name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="Given name is too long."
     * )
     */
    protected $givenName;

}
```

I've created 2 forms, one for the Contact entity and one for the Name entity. I'm then embedding the Name form into the Contact form.

```
class ContactType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', new NameType());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'         => AcmeCoreBundle\Entity\Contact,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'error_bubbling'     => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_contact';
    }
}

class NameType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('given_name', 'text', array(
                'required'       => true,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'     => AcmeCoreBundle\Entity\Name,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_name';
    }
}
```

I've set `cascade_validation` to `true` on the Contact form, which is the root form, and `error_bubbling` to `false` at all levels. I've tested these config options and they are being set.

However the error message is being attached to `form.name` and not `form.name.given_name`, which is what I want.

Where am I going wrong?

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

For anyone encountering a similar issue the the problem was with the naming of the form fields.

In my entity the property was named using camelCase as follows:

```
protected $givenName;
```

However in my form I named the field using underscore notation as I believe this is the convention.

```
$builder->add('given_name', 'text');
```

This worked fine for everything except error bubbling. The simple solution was to rename my field as follows:

```
$builder->add('givenName', 'text');
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set error_bubbling to false or true at all. First try removing all the lines that set error_bubbling to false.

Also try adding `'validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup')` to both Types, And then updating your validation file to reference `yourValidationGroup`

Then perhaps as a final attempt add the submit button to the ContactType to make sure that the ContactType is the one being submitted.

```
class ContactType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', new NameType());
        $builder->add('save', 'submit'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'         => AcmeCoreBundle\Entity\Contact,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup'),

        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_contact';
    }
}

class NameType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('given_name', 'text', array(
                'required'       => true,
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'     => AcmeCoreBundle\Entity\Name,
            'validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup'),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_name';
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
It also occured to me that you might be depending on the annotations to do your validation, as opposed to using a validation.yml file in your bundle? (i.e. .../Resources/config/validation.yml)

Comment: Thanks for your help Desi. I've tried everything you've suggested and the result remains the same :( You are correct I am using annotations for my validation. Will this make a difference?

Comment: In fact removing the `error_bubbling` option everywhere has made the given_name error appear on the Contact form and not on the Name form (as before). I want the error to appear on the actual given_name field within the Name form.

Comment: Interesting. I recommend trying a validation.yml in the bundle where you can set the validation group, but I am wondering if there is something going on with your form view code. How are you presenting the form? Are you using custom form fields and perhaps leaving out the form-error for the form-row?

Comment: Thanx, I was missing `'cascade_validation' => true,` in a project, thinking it was error_bubbling error